# A very basic question about building a chrome extension with html css and js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm a beginner in building codes, and I'm building a chrome extension. I have done all the things the book told me, but it doesn't work. This is part of my HTML and Js code. If I check the "clear-history-checkbox"check box, I want the JS to delete all the history.

```
로그삭제 <input type="checkbox" id="clear-history-checkbox" onclick="clearHistory()">
```

```
JS: function clearHistory() {
  chrome.history.deleteAll(function() {
    alert("History cleared!");
  });
}
```

I've placed  in body and head, but it didn't work.